# How can I dock ArcToolbox in ArcMap 10 custom template and make it stay?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Here is the situation:
Because UI Controls cannot be saved to Normal.mxt like they used to I had to create an empty document with all my custom VBA code that is mostly called from the local document-level UI controls. (Until I have time to get proficient with .NET things will have to run this way)
All is good although it would have been nice to have Normal.mxt-level UI Controls back...
Whenever I need custom functionality i start creating the new document within my Custom Template. One annoying problem I have is that I have to dock ArcToolbox every time i open a document created from the custom template. It will just not stay docked whether I save the custom template with it docked or the Normal.mxt. Normal template documents are fine, ArcToolbox is where i want it, just the custom template is misbehaving. 
Any ideas?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running MxdDoctor corrects this issue but unfortunately the utility also removes customization (UI Controls & toolbars)

Answer (score 3):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000001000000

The handle to the ArcToolbox dockable window.

[IArcToolbox.hWnd Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#/hWnd_Property/00250000001z000000/)

You can create new templates by saving map documents in your user profile that only you will see. Add user-defined categories (folders) and map document templates to the following location:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates

Tip - To create multiple System template locations, you can modify the following registry key, separating folders with a semicolon (;).

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Settings\TemplateDir
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Bin\Templates;E:\More
>   System Templates

Customizing the user interface
**With ArcGIS 10, map documents referencing map templates (.mxt) files for configuring user interfaces is no longer supported**. ArcGIS 9.3.1 map documents referencing .mxt will continue to work at ArcGIS 10; however, you cannot create new .mxt files or modify existing .mxt files for saving user interface customizations.

http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/06/14/What_1920_s-new-for-map-templates-in-ArcGIS-10.aspx